# Difference Between Opting In and Out of Courtesy Overdrafts

Tags: savings, overdraft

Let's say you had $50 as a balance in your savings account. You go out and buy something that costs $250.

So, your balance is now 50 - 250 = - 200 dollars.

> What is the difference between **Opting In** vs **Opting Out** of a courtesy overdraft option?

From what I have read, opting in means you get an overdraft fee of say 36 dollars. So, then your balance becomes -236 dollars.

However, doesn't opting out still result in a fee? I mean I think it still is even called an overdraft. Is the fee more when you opt-out? I just would like to understand the difference between these two things.

Comment: Very likely dependent on a particular bank's Ts&Cs, but a very quick search for "courtesy overdraft" would suggest that _without_ one in place, a transaction that would make you overdrawn is _more likely_ (but not guaranteed) to be rejected (but if allowed, you'd be paying fees). Also, if you're in the US, my understanding (I'm not) is that savings accounts are fairly restricted: can you actually pay-by-card from a savings account?

Comment: You can use your savings account to pay for something by card. It is more common I think to link your checking account to your credit card. It just is weird that opting-out would still allow a $36 fee and still be called an overdraft. I would just prefer the payment not to go through. I just don't see much of a difference between these two options. Other than a slight difference that opting-in means "more likely" to go through on specific payments. I just didn't know if I was missing something major as far as the difference between these two ideas go.

Comment: I expect it depends on jurisdiction, perhaps states if you're in the US, and perhaps the individual bank's policies.  My understanding - though I've never had an overdraft option myself - is that if you opt out, your purchase would be declined if paying by debit card, or you would have bad check charges if you used a paper check.